# Почему регистронезависимая mb_stristr зависит от регистра для русского языка?

Tags: php

Почему false?

```
var_dump(mb_stristr('Федоров', 'ф', 'UTF-8'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сама функция:

```
mb_stristr(string $haystack, string $needle, boolean $part = false, string $encoding = null)
```

Кодировку, которые вы передаете 3-им параметром стоит передавать 4-им. Получается:

```
var_dump(mb_stristr('Федоров', 'ф', false, 'UTF-8'));
```

В документации написано, что 3-ий параметр должен быть типа `boolen`. По умолчанию там стоит `false`, это значит, что он возвращает все `$haystack` **от** первого вхождения `$needle` до конца. Если поставить значение `true`, он возвращает все `$haystack` от начала **до** первого вхождения `$needle`.

Comment: Спасибо. Не заметил.